# How to handle data in direct children routes

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, express, react-router-v4

Im new in React and single apps and I have a question in this approach.

Im using React-router 4. When routing lets say I have a ToDos component (myapp.com/todos) that when visiting I fetch the ToDos data to something like "myapp.com/api/todos.json" and get the ToDos list and then render every ToDo, and if I want to go to something like ToDo component where you show the ToDo details would be a route like "todos/:todoid" then I use a  and go to the ToDo detail and that works fine, but what happen when a user visit directly the "todos/1"?. Should I fetch the data from the server corresponding to that particular todo? something like "myapp.com/api/todos/1.json" ? or should I load the ToDo component and get all the todos ?

Is important because then I have to server rendering the routes and pass some props to the route like the open graph tags.

Any advice or tutorial or course would be appreciate. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need server side rendering, when the user opens 'todos/1' directly, then render ToDo-detail component and use onComponentDidMount to fetch('api/todos/1').

Comment: I have to use server side rendering because I need to render the open graph tags (and some other SEO props ), otherwise Crawlers like Facebook won't fetch the metadata, so I can't use the onComponentDidMount to fetch the data